# Transition for moving objects with position: fixed?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

This seems like it should be a simple problem, but I'm by no means a CSS expert, and I've been beating my head against the wall trying to figure it out. So I've got a ContentHeader element, and when the user scrolls down past a certain point, I want it to slide up to cover the NavigationHeader element. I'm changing the position of ContentHeader by changing the className property from "content-header" to "content-header top", which works, but ContentHeader just jumps into the new position instead of transitioning smoothly. This is the CSS I'm using currently:

```
.content-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 1030;
    padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
    transition: top 1s linear;
}
.content-header.top {
    top: 0;
}
```

If you need to see the JavaScript, let me know and I can add that as well, but it's basically just doing ...

```
<section className={className} ...
```

... where the value of className would vary depending on where ContentHeader should be positioned. I thought maybe the problem was that this is happening inside a React render block and that was skipping the transition, but I tried changing the class with an onClick event that wouldn't force a re-render, and the results were the same. If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing `px` on your `top` value, which should read `top: 50px;`

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').toggleClass('top');
})
```

```css
.content-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 1030;
  padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
  transition: top 1s linear;
}

.content-header.top {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="content-header">header</h1>
<button>click</button>
```

That said, I would use `transform: translateY();` instead of `top` because that's more performant. Using a `transition` or `animation` with `transform` get GPU acceleration, where transitioning `top` does not.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('h1').toggleClass('top');
})
```

```css
.content-header {
  position: fixed;
  transform: translateY(50px);
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 1030;
  padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}

.content-header.top {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="content-header">header</h1>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer, especially with the inclusion of using `transform` over `top`. We recently did a very animation heavy site as a team, and the performance difference can be staggering.

Answer (score 5):

Try giving the initial `top` value a unit, for example: `top: 50px`.

```
.content-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px; // add `px` unit here
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 1030;
    padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
    transition: top 1s linear;
}
```